# Capturing video in Linux from a frame buffer in C/C++

Tags: linux, video, video-capture

I would like to ask you to recommend me a C/C++ library to capture video.

I am getting frames from a camera at 16 bits per pixel (RGB), and I would like to save those frames in a video format in an efficient way to be able to look at it in the future.

Would you please recommend me a good C/C++ library that I can use under Linux please?

A Google search gives me a lot of libraries, and I am really not sure which one does a good job and is widely used. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know -- the predominat library is [Video4Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux) -- however I have not tried it myself, but the list of applications using/supporting it is impressive.

**Addition:**
For Multi media Encoding [GStreamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer) is probably one of the most used frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for this library. It appears to me that this library is useful to get a frame buffer from a device to the host. I actually already did that part, what I need is to save it in an appropriate video format, such as MPEG or AVI, but I need a library that can do that efficiently as I pass my frame buffer to it.

Comment: I see -- I think that would be GStreamer you would want then instead.

Comment: @Jary ...FFMPEG (http://ffmpeg.org) is the best open source audio video converter I think...I am using it for last two years without any problem...It can convert video to almost all formats.